Equivalent conditions of injective module
My question: Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Then an $R$-module $E$ is injective module if and only if,  for any ideal $I$ of $R$, every exact sequence $0 \rightarrow E \rightarrow B \rightarrow R / I \rightarrow 0$ is split.
My attempt: The problem involves the ideal $I$ of $R$, so I am considering using Baer's lemma. However, I am unsure how to construct an extension and how to use the condition of the split exact sequence. I have also thought about $Ext^{1}_{R}(R / I, E)$, but it seems unnecessary to make things that complicated. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

What is "the" exact sequence $0 \to E \to B \to R/I \to 0$? What even is $B$? Do you mean every exact sequence of that form?

Yes, it should be any exact sequence of this form.

Using the characterisation of $\text{Ext}^1$ in terms of exact sequences, it inmediately follows from Baer's criterion the long exact sequence for $\text{Ext}$ (if you do not know how, I can give further details). I will think of a more "rudimentary" way of doing this ...
